# Change texture onclick three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

im working with three.js and im trying to make a configurator, i need to change the

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "js/textura.jpg" );
```

to

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "js/textura2.jpg" );
```

but i cannot get it to work, im using

```
<button onclick="THREE.TextureLoader().load(js/textura2.jpg)">CLICK</button>
```

also i have the

```
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

thanks

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#boton2").click(function(){
  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();          

 loader.load( "js/maniqui.json", function(geometry) {

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "js/textura3.jpg" );
 var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture});
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 texture.needsUpdate = true;
 scene.add(mesh)
```

});

with this i change the texture, but it reload the mesh again (pretty dumb i know) so for every different texture i have a different button, i cant make it work  without the scene.add(mesh)

and here is the main code

```
var scene, camera, renderer;





init();
animate();


function init() {


  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
      HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true,alpha:true});
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 20000);
  camera.position.set(0,0,15);
  scene.add(camera);


  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });





scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ));




  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();          

 loader.load( "js/maniqui.json", function(geometry) {

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "js/textura.jpg" );
 var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:texture, color: 0xffffff});
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 texture.needsUpdate = true;
 scene.add(mesh)
```

});

```
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

}





function animate() {


  requestAnimationFrame(animate);


  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();

}
```

Comment: What you have will only load a texture, and won't do anything with it. Your button click should call a function, which can load the texture and update the **material** of the object. Can you provide a working minimal example of your code (as a snippet, jsfiddle, or plunker), so we have something to work with?

Comment: Well i already solved the thing with a jquery .click, i made a function but the function needs to add the element again to the scene, i cant get it to work without add to scene mesh

Comment: As long as you can access the **`Mesh`**, you can modify and replace its **material**. You should not need to re-add the `Mesh`. Can you please share the code from your button click solution, so we have some place to start?

Comment: i updated the code, thats what im using actually to change the texture and the main code